# creating a dashboard in a laravel project

Tags: laravel, localhost, dashboard

In my laravel project i need to make a dynamic dashboard something like a power bi dashboard and i'm new to everything related to laravel. My main problem is to add or to create a dashboard in a laravel project. For example when the user go to the home page he finds a dashboard that contains statistics of different axes and fields. I used to work with power bi and i know how to integrate a power bi report in laravel however it needs a microsoft professional account to do this but the compony i'm working with doesn't want to buy a license because they need the doashbord for them only and they are not gowing to give it to their clients so i don't know how to make a dynamic dashboard in which the company's developpers can add filters when they need to.

PS: I'm still a student and this is an internship project that I'm creating on localhost.

Any advice or link is welcomed (should I use a language or a BI tool and if so what tool to use for free...).
Thank you in advance.